# is it possible to integerate java and php

Tags: java, php

i need to integrate an java class to php program is it possible.??if so please explain???

Comment: Integrate in what sense? Do you want the output of the Java class to your PHP program as data input?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is possible. Check this : [PHP to Java bridge](http://www.projectzero.org/sMash/1.1.x/docs/zero.devguide.doc/zero.php/ZeroAdvancedPHPJavaBridge.html)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It is possible. Please refer to the [Manual on PHP/Java Integration](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.java.php)

[Example](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/java.examples-basic.php)

```
// get instance of Java class java.lang.System in PHP
$system = new Java('java.lang.System');

// demonstrate property access
echo 'Java version=' . $system->getProperty('java.version') . '<br />';
echo 'Java vendor=' . $system->getProperty('java.vendor') . '<br />';
echo 'OS=' . $system->getProperty('os.name') . ' ' .
             $system->getProperty('os.version') . ' on ' .
             $system->getProperty('os.arch') . ' <br />';

// java.util.Date example
$formatter = new Java('java.text.SimpleDateFormat',
                      "EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy 'at' h:mm:ss a zzzz");

echo $formatter->format(new Java('java.util.Date'));
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can Start a java application as any other application from PHP using [exec](http://php.net/exec).
- You can interop using [WebServices](http://java.sun.com/webservices/)