# java model layer, php templating and session handling and so on, html/ccs/javascript client-side

Tags: java, php

I have partially written a web application in php. It has some large data processing needs. Writing the model/controller layer in php is not fun as it isn't particularly good as far as oop and so on goes. I would like to move this logic to a java application that is simply called or accessed by the php. What would be the best way to go about doing this?

How do companies like google and so on work? They use php, but do they use it for model/controller/data processing-type logic? From what I can figure out, they use a lot of c++/java for this. How do they connect that to php?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280420/is-it-possible-to-integerate-java-and-php